# Replicate in space an object with position and orientation from GPU kernel

Tags: opengl, cuda, opencl, vbo

### Context

I am doing swarm simulation using GPU programming (both OpenCL and CUDA,
but not at the same time of course) for scientific purpose.
I use OpenGL for display.

### Goal

I would like to draw the same object —namely the swarming particle, can be a simple triangle in 2D— N times at different positions and with
different orientations in the most efficient way knowing that:

- the object is always exactly the same
- the positions and orientations are calculated on the GPU and thus stored in the GPU memory
- the number of particles N can be large

### Current solution

So far, to avoid sending back the data to the CPU, I store the position and
orientation arrays in a VBO and use:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, position_vbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, velocity_vbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, N);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

to draw a set of points with color-coded velocity without copying back the arrays to the CPU.

What I would like to do is something like drawing a full object instead of a simple point
using a similar way *ie* without copying back the VBO's to the CPU.

Basically I would like to store on the GPU the *model* of an object
(a Display List? a Vertex Array?) and to use the positions and orientations on the GPU
to draw the object N times **without sending data back to the CPU**.

Is it possible and how? Else, how should I do it?

PS: I like keeping the code clean so I would rather separate the display issues from the swarming kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this with a geometry shader (available in OpenGL 3.2).  See [this tutorial](http://cirl.missouri.edu/gpu/glsl_lessons/glsl_geometry_shader/index.html) for specific information.

In your case, you need to make the input type and output type of the geometry shader to GL_POINTS and GL_TRIANGLES respectively, and in your geometry shader, emit the 3 vertices of your triangle for each incoming point vertex.

Comment: It seems like a good solution to my problem. Any alternative without using extensions?

Comment: @Simon         the geometry shader is available in OpenGL 3.2, so if your driver supports that version, you don't need extension